# How to display a xaml code provided in a text file, on WPF UI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

At run time I am capturing user inputs on basis of that I am creating a dynamic view in form of XAML, I need to render this XAML code on WPF UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options, depending on exactly what you want to do.

An uncompiled file can be transformed into one ui element using Xamlreader.Load. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.load?view=netframework-4.8
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Resources/774/how-to-load-xaml-in-xamlreader.aspx

A String can be similarly transformed using xamlreader.parse.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.parse?view=netframework-4.8

Once you have a control you can then use it. EG set the content of a contentcontrol to your control and it will appear.

You can also merge in an uncompiled resource dictionary. Which could have controls and or resources in them.

You can see a number of related techniques in the series of samples linked here:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28797.wpf-dynamic-xaml.aspx

Comment: I’d bet money that this is a particularly virulent X/Y problem.

Comment: Maybe. The techniques are occasionally useful. Having the end xaml available to see what happens makes diagnosing problems a lot easier than using say factory methods to generate UI on the fly.

Comment: Factory methods are even worse, true.

Comment: My point is that he probably doesn’t need to reinvent data templating, not that he’s reinventing it the wrong way.